# How can I make Vuex 'invisible' in VueJS DevTools

Tags: vue.js, store, vuex

There is a config option for vuejs to turn off inspection for the components. This is accessed through

```
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

When you set that code before initializing Vue, the user (or you) will not be able to inspect the components and you will get the following message
[vue devtools disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWisa.png)

I am looking for a similar config for vuex because even with the Vue Js devtools turned off, I can still see the store including mutations and the ability to undo them which is something I don't want.

Is there a way to turn off vuex store inspection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find any similar flags to disable `Vuex Devtools`. But it looks like running the following regularly (every 200ms or so) will keep the `Vuex` tab non-readable.

```
window.__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.emit('vuex:init', {})
```

For example:

```
setInterval(() => {
      window.__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.emit('vuex:init', {})
}, 200)
```

Comment: Thanks. Will there not be a performance cost? How exactly should I run it? In my main js file before Vue init or in store.js?

Comment: Running it asynchronously should be fine. Use `setInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  Vue.config.devtools = false
  Vue.config.productionTip = false
}
```

Adding the code above to app.js entry file and setting the environment with build tools solved my problem.

[image: VueX store not detected in production as desired]

Answer (score 0):

For any future visitors this was [fixed in Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/pull/881) so setting `Vue.config.devtools = false` should disable Vuex as well.